# Multi-stage query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to see all results matching a particular Guid, as well as all results matching a particular field (`fish_tag`) from the first results, whether they have the Guid or not.

For example, in Stage 1 I search for eb23c255-2986-4bf5-8b99-dd123affe739, and say 20 results are returned. Of the 20, some have nothing in their `fish_tag` field, and some have values (not necessarily unique). In Stage 2 I search only the `fish_tag` field for all the values returned in Stage 1 and many more results are returned, say 100. Included in the Stage 2 results are the results from Stage 1 with the searched `fish_tag`s.

Ideally I am looking for a one query to return the combination/concatenation of Stage 1 and Stage 2, or if that is not possible to return Stage 2 in one query.

Is it possible to craft such a multi-stage query in Kibana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Elastcsearch search query is one-pass. So there is no a way to search in results of previous search

You can use the `bool` query (as @Musab Dogan adviced) and compose a condition:

(GUID == 'eb23c255-2986-4bf5-8b99-dd123affe739') AND (fish_tag IS NOT empty)

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch boolean query can help you to combine multiple conditions/queries. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

You can also use boolean queries in Kibana visualizations/dashboards. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/packetbeat/current/kibana-queries-filters.html#_boolean_queries

Eg.

```
type: mysql AND method: INSERT AND status: Error
```

or

```
(method: INSERT OR method: UPDATE) AND event.duration >= 30000000
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I am looking for a query using query results, which this answer does not address.

Comment: For the next time please ask your question more clear. You need to define `"I am looking for a query using query results"` in your question. If you don't define it, I can't answer properly.